# Composer - Unknown downloader type: h - Getting this error for a repo on packigist

Tags: composer-php

I just put up a package on `packagist` and I tried to run a `composer update` and am getting the error:

```
Unknown downloader type: h. Available types: git, svn, hg, perforce, zip, rar, tar, gzip, phar, file.
```

In the main project file I have this:

```
"require": {
    //.......
    "cyphix333/sbb-code-parser": "dev-master"
},
```

The `composer.json` file for `cyphix333/sbb-code-parser` is:

```
{
    "name": "cyphix333/sbb-code-parser",
    "description": "SBBCodeParser is a simple BBCode parser",
    "keywords": [
        "SBBCodeParser"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/samclarke/SBBCodeParser",
    "canonical": "https://github.com/cyphix333/SBBCodeParser",
    "source": "https://github.com/cyphix333/SBBCodeParser/tree/master",
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["SBBCodeParser.php","classes/"]
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Sam Clarke"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3"
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes to your composer.json: dropped canonical and source; added type library.

Give this one a try:

```
{
    "name": "cyphix333/sbb-code-parser",
    "description": "SBBCodeParser is a simple BBCode parser",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/samclarke/SBBCodeParser",
    "keywords": ["SBBCodeParser"],
    "type": "library",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Sam Clarke"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["SBBCodeParser.php", "classes/"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

If you just started getting this error, try `composer clear-cache` and/or delete `~/.composer` and `vendor`.

The specific error I was getting was:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                  
  Unknown downloader type: . Available types: git, svn, fossil, hg, perforce, zip, rar, tar, gzip, xz, phar,  
   file, path.
```

I just deleted everything and then tried again; works now.

I'm using

```
Composer version 1.2.0 2016-07-19 01:28:52
```

Comment: In my situation I had to delete .composer.lock file as well

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this issue deleting the vendor directory.

```
rm -Rf vendor
```

And then running:

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 1):

I did resolve this error after updating the composer version.

The installation did not work with composer v2.
Passing to the v1 version works.

```
composer self-update --1
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue too, we had a human error in our `composer.json`. The `dist` part of one of our custom repositories was entered with a faulty downloader type (as stated in the error message).

```
  {
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
      "name": "campaignmonitor/createsend-php",
      "type": "drupal-library",
      "version": "dev-master",
      "dist": {
        "url": "https://github.com/campaignmonitor/createsend-php.git",
        "type": "drupal-library"
      },
      "source": {
        "url": "https://github.com/campaignmonitor/createsend-php.git",
        "type": "git",
        "reference": "master"
      }
    }
  }
```

Note that the `dist`'s `type` is entered as `drupal-library`, that is the package type, not the downloader type. We corrected this by using the following for `dist`:

```
      "dist": {
        "url": "https://github.com/campaignmonitor/createsend-php/archive/master.zip",
        "type": "zip"
      },
```

As we developed this project we had no problems when running `composer install` locally. We encountered this error when making the project production ready, using `--prefer-dist`. Obviously, it will only then use `dist` over `source` and then encounter this error.

**Disclaimer**: This case is somewhat different then the original question, though it's highly relatable and this question came up on top when trying to search for the answer. I hope this is okay.